# SSRS Unmerge Matrix Columns

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-tablix

I have a matrix report with 9 Row Groups and 1 Column Group (Months).

Instead of showing duplicate rows on the row groups, SSRS and Excel merge those fields. I would like them unmerged! I would like them to duplicate on my report.

I tried going to the parent group and grouping by every other field. This worked *until* I added two rows within the group, (which I need).

I guess you could also say that I really want my row groups to look like a table. If there's a better way to do that, I'm all ears!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym6tH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is it **TYPE** field that you need all the lines for?

The bracket to the left (under Row Groups) indicates that you are **Grouping** on something. Remove the Group Only (but not the rows and columns) so you are not grouping and all lines will be displayed.

[image]